# How to create changing group identifier in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, window, mariadb

I have a table in my MariaDb which looks like the following table and need to create the "group" column (see output).
The group changes if the combination of KEY_A and KEY_B changes in the order of LOAD_DATE (see output).
I'm not able to find a proper SQL to generate the "group" column.

Maybe someone has an idea  how to solve this in MariaDB?

TestData:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test AS 
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-01') AS LOAD_DATE
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'B' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-02') 
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-03') 
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-04') 
UNION
SELECT 'BBB' AS KEY_A,'C' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-04') 
UNION
SELECT 'CCC' AS KEY_A,'D' AS KEY_B,DATE('2010-01-04') ;
```

Output:

```
KEY_A; KEY_B; LOAD_DATE;  group

AAA;   A;     2010-01-01;  1
AAA;   B;     2010-01-02;  2
AAA;   A;     2010-01-03;  3
AAA;   A;     2010-01-04;  3
BBB;   C;     2010-01-04;  1
CCC;   D;     2010-01-04;  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a gaps-and-islands problem.

You can solve this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum( case when key_b = prev_key_b then 0 else 1 end ) over (partition by key_a order by load_date) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(key_b) over (partition by key_a order by load_data) as prev_key_b
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: @Lars . . . I fixed the problem.  The 0/1 was backwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! you save me @Gordon Linoff. If someone wants to know more about this problem see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffNngUTqYBM).

Answer (score 0):

Your Test Data is actually written incorrectly.

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TestDB.test AS 
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-01') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'B' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-02') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-03') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'AAA' AS KEY_A,'A' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-04') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'BBB' AS KEY_A,'C' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-04') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'CCC' AS KEY_A,'D' AS KEY_B, DATE('2010-01-04') AS LOAD_DATE FROM DUAL
;
```